# Calculate limits with absolute value

Tags: calculus, limits

Does this limits exist?

$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{|x-1|}{2x^2-x-1}$

I know I can do this:

$$ \frac{|x-1|}{(x-1)(2x+1)}$$

but what do I do with the absolute value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the definition of absolute value and look at: $$\lim_{x \to 1^+} \frac{|x-1|}{2x^2-x-1} = \lim_{x \to 1^+} \frac{x-1}{2x^2-x-1} \quad \mbox{and} \quad \lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{|x-1|}{2x^2-x-1}= \lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{-(x-1)}{2x^2-x-1}.$$

Comment: So, according to you, the limit does not exist? since we get for $ x \to 1^+ $ that the limit is $\frac{1}{3}$ and when $ x \to 1^- $ the limit is $-\frac{1}{3}$, am I right?

Comment: That's right! You can do a quick check using, say, L'Hospital's rule in each lateral limit separately.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: try to calculate  limits from left and from right ($x<1$ and $x>1$, respectively).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. Consider right and left limits.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $\frac{|x−1|}{x−1}=\text{sgn}(x-1)$, so $$f(x)=\frac{|x−1|}{(x−1)(2x+1)}=\frac{\text{sgn}(x-1)}{2x+1}=\text{sgn}(x-1)g(x)=\begin{cases}g(x) & x>1\\
-g(x) & x<1
\end{cases}$$
where $g(x)=\frac{1}{2x+1}\to \frac{1}{3}$ as $x\to 1^{\pm}$.

You have a discontinuity in $x=1$ and the limits are
$$
\lim_{x\to 1^{\pm}}f(x)=\pm\frac{1}{3}.
$$